# Compare archive and master database content

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle, db2

I have a master database in DB2 9.1 and I created a database in Oracle 12g to archive it. I have done it successfully with some datatype change programmatically.

I want to compare the content of two master (in DB2) and archive (in Oracle) databases to ensure the correctness of content transfer. Because of some limitations, I can not use any tools to do this. So I must be doing it programmatically with  Java, C# or...

My first solution is to read rows content from the master database in Byte and concatenate columns to gather and create hashcode for each master and archive rows in the database and compare this hash codes. This is very time-consuming in big tables (having types of CLOB and BLOB and row update).
Does anyone have a good idea?

Comment: If you changed data types of some columns, as you say, comparing their byte representations is unlikely to succeed, even if the values are semantically equal. You will need to rethink your approach.

Comment: Why did you tag sql server if it is not related?

Comment: Why not use DB2 for the archive too? Oracle seems a needless complication.

Comment: My goal is to migrate to Oracle so I changed data types as mentioned in [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E39885_01/doc.40/e18460/oracle_db2_compared.htm#RPTID146) document (because DB2 data types are not same as Oracle) and I search a solution for my comparison problem.
 I tagged SQL-Server because it can help to get more idea's. my problem is typical. if anyone wants to migrate DB2 to SQL-Server encountered with this problem too.